# Синхронизация контекстов в сервисе

Tags: c#, многопоточность, service

Есть сервис

```
class MainService : ServiceBase 
{
  event EventHandler MyEvent;
  Thread m_Thread = null;
  ...
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  { 
    //тут System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId = 1
    MyEvent += delegate { 
      //Тут System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId = 5
    };
    m_Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MonitorThread));
    m_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    m_Thread.Start();
  }
  protected override void OnStop()
  {
    m_Thread.Abort();
  }
  ...
  private void MonitorThread()
  {
    //Something
    MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArg.Empty);
    //Something
  }
  ...
}
```

в `MonitorThread` иногда вызываются события `MyEvent`, естественно вызов происходит в потоке отличного от основного потока, как мне вызвать событие или какой-либо метод по событию в основном потоке???

PS: `SynchronizationContext.Current` в сервисе = null

PS2: Сборка в .Net Framework 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, основной поток в вин-службах полностью отведен под управление временем жизни и системные события (OnStart, OnStop и т.п.)

Если вам зачем-то нужен основной поток - надо просто выбрать один из ваших дополнительных потоков и "назначить" его основным.

Если вас не устраивает ваш MonitorThread в качестве такового - держите реализацию потока с очередью сообщений:

```
class QueueSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>();

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        try { queue.Add(new WorkItem(d, state)); }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { if (Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break(); }
        // Если уже был вызван CompleteAdding - мы уже не можем добавить элемент в очередь, но и позволять службе падать также не стоит
        // (нет ничего глупее чем программа которая падает при закрытии). Поэтому лучшее что тут можно сделать - это забыть.
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var e = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false))
            {
                queue.Add(new WorkItem(d, state, e));
                e.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { if (Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break(); }
        // Если уже был вызван CompleteAdding - мы уже не можем добавить элемент в очередь, но и позволять службе падать также не стоит
        // (нет ничего глупее чем программа которая падает при закрытии). Поэтому лучшее что тут можно сделать - это забыть.
    }

    public bool ProcessQueue(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var wi in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
                wi.Execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { return false; }
    }

    public void Complete() => queue.CompleteAdding();
    public void Dispose() => queue.Dispose();

    private class WorkItem
    {
        private SendOrPostCallback d;
        private object state;
        private ManualResetEvent e;

        public WorkItem(SendOrPostCallback d, object state, ManualResetEvent e = null)
        {
            this.d = d;
            this.state = state;
            this.e = e;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            try { d(state); }
            finally { e?.Set(); }
        }
    }
}

class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private QueueSynchronizationContext ctx;
    private Thread mainThread;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.ctx = new QueueSynchronizationContext();
        this.mainThread = new Thread(MainThread);
        this.mainThread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // Не забыть отменить фоновые задачи и дождаться их завершения 
        // ПЕРЕД вызовом ctx.Complete()!
        ctx.Complete();
        mainThread.Join();
        ctx.Dispose();
    }

    private void MainThread()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctx);
        ctx.ProcessQueue(CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: BlockingCollection не доступен в .Net 2.0 к сожалению

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик ну блокирующую очередь-то написать - дело нехитрое... Один Queue и немного мониторов

Comment: Да, думаю это вариант